# I do not know how to proof this. An undirected graph $G$ with $n$ vertexes is connected if that graph has more than $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$ edges.

Tags: graph-theory

I do not know how to proof this.
An undirected graph $G$ with $n$ vertexes is connected if that graph has more than $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$ edges.

Comment: Have you had any thoughts about a possible approach?

Answer (score 3):

One way is by induction on $n$. The base case can easily be checked.

For the induction step, we are given a graph $G$ of $n+1$ vertices with more than $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges.

Case 1: All vertices have degree $n$. Then we have a complete graph which is connected.

Case 2a: Some (but not all) vertex/vertices have degree $n$. Then in the neighborhood of these vertices there must contain a vertex $v$ with degree $1 \leq d(v) \leq n-1$.

Case 2b: no vertex has degree $n$. Then there exists a vertex $v$ with degree $1 \leq d(v) \leq n-1$.

Now consider $G-v$. It has $n$ vertices and $e(G-v) > \frac{n(n-1)}{2} - d(v) \geq \frac{n(n-1)}{2} - (n-1) = \frac{n^2 - 3n + 2}{2} = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$.

By our induction hypothesis, $G-v$ is connected. Since $v$ is connected to $G-v$, $G$ is connected.

** Thanks to Klave for spotting and highlighting my mistake in my initial attempt

Comment: There is a sign error : (n − 1)(n − 2) = n² − 3n + 2 which is > than n² − 3n.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my error! Have attempted to fix it in the edit

Answer (score 3):

Let $G(V,E)$ be a graph with $|V|=n$ vertices and $|E|=m$ edges. We need to show that if $m>(n-1)(n-2)/2$, then $G$ is connected. It's sufficient to show the contrapositive, i.e., if $m\leq (n-1)(n-2)/2$, then $G$ is disconnected.

First note that a disconnected graph with the most edges is the union of a complete graph on $n-1$ vertices and an isolated vertex. In this case, the disconnected graph has $\binom{n-1}{2}=(n-1)(n-2)/2$ edges. QED.

Comment: Can you easily show that the disconnected graph with the most edges is the union of $K_{n-1}$ and $K_1$ ?

Comment: @manuellafond: Consider adding one more edge to $K_{n-1}$ disjoint union $\{v\}$. Since $K_{n-1}$ is already complete, the only way one can do that is by adding an edge between the isolated vertex $v$ and one vertex of $K_{n-1}$. But now the graph is connected.

Comment: Yes, but how does that tell you that the disconnected graph with the most edges isn't $K_{j}$ disjoint union $K_{n - j}$ for some $j$ other than 1 ?  Anyway, it's not to be picky or anything.  I had the same proof idea as yours, but didn't post it because of this simple fact, which is obvious but does require some additional explanations (which I couldn't formulate in a single sentence, and I got lazy - hence my question :) )

Comment: @manuellafond: Consider the inequality for $ 1\leq m\leq n$ $$\binom{m}{2}+\binom{n-m}{2}\leq \binom{n-1}{2}$$ where $n\geq 1$

Comment: What you stated isn't the contrapositive. $G$ being disconnected if $m \leq (n-1)(n-2)/2$ does NOT imply that $G$ is connected so long as $m > (n-1)(n-2)/2$. To obtain the contrapositive, you need to negate both sides and flip the direction of implication, so the contrapositive here is $G$ disconnected $\Rightarrow m \leq (n-1)(n-2)/2$.